# I can't pass the ArrayList<T> class I created via module.exports to typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a class ArrayList, I use it for laboratory work, I need to “supposedly” make a dynamic array, but I already have javascript. So when I pass this class, I can’t call the constructor. Сan declare it like this let tmp: ArrayList, but you can’t call the constructor, that is, let tmp: ArrayList = new ArrayList(); gives an error message

I will export the file from

```
class ArrayList<T> {
    private capacity: number;
    private length: number;
    private array: T[];

    constructor(capacity: number = 10) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.length = 0;
        this.array = new Array<T>(this.capacity);
    }

    private resize(newCapacity: number): void {
        const newArray = new Array<T>(newCapacity);
        for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            newArray[i] = this.array[i];
        }
        this.array = newArray;
        this.capacity = newCapacity;
    }

    size(): number {
        return this.array.length;
    }

    isEmpty(): boolean {
        return this.array.length === 0;
    }

    get(index: number): T | undefined {
        if (index < 0 || index >= this.length) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return this.array[index];
    }
}

module.exports = ArrayList;
```

file where I import

```
const ArrayList = require("./ArrayList");
let newGraph: ArrayList<ArrayList<number>> = new ArrayList<ArrayList<number>>();// here's the problem
```

Comment: As the error mesage tells you - you missed the `new` keyword. "*Value of type 'typeof ArrayList' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?(2348)*" https://tsplay.dev/WzQ2km

Comment: there should be the word "new", this line doesn’t work with it either.

Comment: It does in the playground link I posted. Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: so this is the minimum code for an error to appear, the word “new” does not work for me in this case and I cannot write <> either and I don’t know what to do with it.